# How to request an operation from a component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I have a component that is a "MS Paint" simulator. I want to enable users of the component to ask for the current image, but it's not necessarily trivial - various layers need to be merged and whatnot. How can I make this available, especially if it's overall a time consuming/async operation? I could do something like pass in a state like `setGetImageRequested(someCallbackHandler)` which would then do the work and call the handler, but is there an easier way to define a function to do this without all the context/state being passed around?

If it helps...

```
// Library code
const MSPaint = () => {
    const canvas1 = useRef(undefined)
    const canvas2 = useRef(undefined)

    return (<>
        <canvas ref={canvas1} />
        <canvas ref={canvas2} />
    </>)
}

export async function getPNG() {
    // do something to merge the canvases, return the result
}

// Client code
const MyClientFunct = async () => {
    const png = await getPNG()
    // do something with png

    return (<MSPaint />)
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you over complicate your component set up and splitting then yes, it can be difficult to communicate between them. That's the price you pay.